# Check if a vector/angle intersects area

Tags: javascript, canvas

What I'm trying to do is this:
  I have two (x, y)points, p1 and p2, and a rotation value from p1 (angle in radians). 
P2 has also two other variables, a width and height, that I will call p2w and p2h. I want to check if the angle from p1 intersects the bounds of p2, in a radius of the width and/or height.

In other words, if the angle "cuts through" the square of center p2, width p2w and height p2h.

Here's a graph for better understanding:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v12Cs.png

What I've been trying to do is this:

```
if( p1.rot > (Math.atan2(p2.y-p2h, p2.x-p2w)) 
&& p1.rot < (Math.atan2(p2.y+p2h, p2.x+p2w)) )
//There's an intersection
```

But as you guess, it doesn't work as intended; is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Captain Math to the rescue!

You are asking whether a ray intersects a rectangle. Here's what we need to do.

Firstly, a ray is defined using either a point and a vector or a point and angle. Since working with vectors is much easier, let's convert your angle to a vector. Using the Pythagorean theorem, your angle phi is identical to the vector `n = {x: Math.cos(phi), y: Math.sin(phi)}`.

I'll rename your variables to make notation easier. I'll denote your p1 with p and your implicitly defined rectangle with r.

Now, for any random point M lying on the ray, the following equations must hold:

```
M.x = p.x + n.x * alpha (1)
M.y = p.y + n.y * alpha
```

for some real alpha. Similarly, for any random point M lying within the rectangle, the following inequalities must hold:

```
M.x >= r.x
M.x <= r.x + r.w
M.y >= r.y
M.y <= r.y + r.h
```

For a point to lie on both the ray and within the the rectangle both the equations and the inequalities must hold. Substituting the values above, we get:

```
p.x + n.x * alpha >= r.x
p.x + n.x * alpha <= r.x + r.w
p.y + n.y * alpha >= r.y
p.y + n.y * alpha <= r.y + r.h
```

Solve for alpha and we get:

```
alpha >= (r.x - p.x) / n.x
alpha <= (r.x + r.w - p.x) / n.x
alpha >= (r.y - p.y) / n.y
alpha <= (r.y + r.h - p.y) / n.y
```

The system above has a solution if and only if:

```
var lowerLimitX = (r.x - p.x) / n.x;
var lowerLimitY = (r.y - p.y) / n.y;
var upperLimitX = (r.x + r.w - p.x) / n.x;
var upperLimitY = (r.y + r.h - p.y) / n.y;
var minAlpha = Math.max(lowerLimitX, lowerLimitY);
var maxAlpha = Math.min(upperLimitX, upperLimitY);
var hasSolution = minAlpha<= maxAlpha;
```

Now, if the system above has a solution, it must be the case that at least one point lies on both the ray and the rectangle, in other words, they intersect.

**Edit:** Here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NikolaDimitroff/3nd2st7x/). Move the mouse around to see the results. Note that, because of the fact that the Y axis grows *downwards* in the HTML canvas API, one must swap the lower and upper limits of the Y axis.

**Edit 2**: If you care about the intersection segment as suggested by @pfannkuchen_gesicht (note that generally, the intersection will be a line segment, not a point), well that's easy as well. As we already know, for the points on the intersection, the ray equations must hold. To find the points themselves, simply substitute alpha with a value within the range [minAlpha; maxAlpha] in (1). For example, the closest point is `p + minAlpha * n`, the farthest is `p + maxAlpha * n` and a random point in between is `p +(minAlpha + Math.random() * (maxAlpha - minAlpha)) * n`.

Comment: really nice approach!
The only thing I'm missing with this is a intersection point(OP didn't ask for that, but would be interesting for some applications), but I think it's a good fast way to pre-test though.

Comment: That was a great explanation, thank you! I will see if it works for my case, but you're best answer anyway

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht See Edit 2.0

Comment: hey, so recently I looked at your answer again and wondered if it was also possible to use this in 3D. Apparently it doesn't work though. Do you have any idea if there is a better way for 3D AABBs to ray test than testing all its sides?

Comment: What makes you think it won't work? The equations stays the same, besides adding the Z coordinate in all calculations.

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff so turns out it won't work as soon as there is a negative component in the direction vector. See: http://gfycat.com/WeeBountifulAfricanfisheagle

Comment: the same issue appears in your jsfiddle when you move the box down: http://jsfiddle.net/f6g12noL/

Comment: That's a good observation. The problem seems to be in the swapped `lowerLimitY` and `upperLimitY`. Swapping them once more will cause the intersection to work only with negative Y's. I'm currently occupied but I'll try to get back to you once I've figured out where the problem is.

Comment: So the issue is actually quite obvious now, after thinking about it more and also asking someone. So it boils down to inequalities and multiplying with negative numbers, which switches it around and thus makes an upper bound a lower bound. So essentially you have to swap the bounds depending on the n.{x,y,z} sign. Also you have to introduce a check if the min/max-alpha is positive and only then it's a valid solution. See: http://jsfiddle.net/rb7e64m9/

Answer (score 1):

**Here's one way to test if your line segment (ray?) and rectangle intersect.**

Just test if the line segment / ray intersects either of the 2 diagonals of the rectangle.

[image]

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
ctx.lineWidth=3;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }


var ray1={x:30,y:250,angle:-Math.PI/3.5};
var ray2={x:30,y:250,angle:-Math.PI/6};
var r={x:100,y:100,w:40,h:40};

ctx.strokeStyle='black';
ctx.strokeRect(r.x,r.y,r.w,r.h);
// this ray intersects the rect
drawRay(ray1,r);
// this ray doesn't intersect the rect
drawRay(ray2,r);


function drawRay(ray,rect){
  var intersects=rayRectIntersect(ray,rect);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(ray.x,ray.y);
  ctx.lineTo(ray.x+1000*Math.cos(ray.angle),ray.y+1000*Math.sin(ray.angle));
  ctx.strokeStyle=(intersects)?'red':'green';
  ctx.stroke();
}

function rayRectIntersect(ray,rect){
  d0={x:rect.x,y:rect.y};
  d1={x:rect.x+rect.w,y:rect.y+rect.h};
  d2={x:rect.x,y:rect.y+rect.h};
  d3={x:rect.x+rect.w,y:rect.y};
  ray0={x:ray.x,y:ray.y};
  ray1={x:ray.x+1000*Math.cos(ray.angle),y:ray.y+1000*Math.sin(ray.angle)};
  var diag1Test=line2lineIntersection(ray0,ray1,d0,d1);
  var diag2Test=line2lineIntersection(ray0,ray1,d2,d3);
  return(diag1Test || diag2Test);
}

// Get interseting point of 2 line segments (if any)
// Attribution: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/
function line2lineIntersection(p0,p1,p2,p3) {

  var unknownA = (p3.x-p2.x) * (p0.y-p2.y) - (p3.y-p2.y) * (p0.x-p2.x);
  var unknownB = (p1.x-p0.x) * (p0.y-p2.y) - (p1.y-p0.y) * (p0.x-p2.x);
  var denominator  = (p3.y-p2.y) * (p1.x-p0.x) - (p3.x-p2.x) * (p1.y-p0.y);        

  // Test if Coincident
  // If the denominator and numerator for the ua and ub are 0
  //    then the two lines are coincident.    
  if(unknownA==0 && unknownB==0 && denominator==0){return(true);}

  // Test if Parallel 
  // If the denominator for the equations for ua and ub is 0
  //     then the two lines are parallel. 
  if (denominator == 0) return false;

  // If the intersection of line segments is required 
  // then it is only necessary to test if ua and ub lie between 0 and 1.
  // Whichever one lies within that range then the corresponding
  // line segment contains the intersection point. 
  // If both lie within the range of 0 to 1 then 
  // the intersection point is within both line segments. 
  unknownA /= denominator;
  unknownB /= denominator;

  var isIntersecting=(unknownA>=0 && unknownA<=1 && unknownB>=0 && unknownB<=1)

  if(!isIntersecting){return(false);}

  return({
    x: p0.x + unknownA * (p1.x-p0.x),
    y: p0.y + unknownA * (p1.y-p0.y)
  });
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>Ray is red if intersecting, green if not</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```